# SSD for single PCIe slot occcupied

Tags: ssd, pcie, sata

I am working on Dell Optiplex 755 Mini Tower (MT). I have upgraded it to Core 2 Quad Q6700 and 8 GB memory. The base board is Dell 0GM819. Tech Specs are **[here](https://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/optix/en/opti_755_techspecs.pdf)** on page 5. The PCI Express x16 connector (SLOT1) is occupied by my NVIDIA GeForce GT 710. But it looks like I have PCI Express x1 connector (SLOT4) and two PCI connector (SLOT2 and 3) unused.

Which kind of SSD (M.2/PICe etc. as well as the brand name) should I buy and where should I put it?

As a last resort, I could put a 2.5" SATA SSD in a caddy but not sure if there are any other better options available.